# Managing session in stateless microservices

Tags: java, microservices

If microservices are stateless , how can we manage session in JSP based projects .Assuming I am breaking age old monolith to microservices .

Comment: Assuming that there is no way to convert your stateful solution into a state-less solution, You might want to consider the use of cookies, which moves this state to the client. You would want to limit the size of  your 'state'. Don't keep fully realized objects in your cookies, instead, keep references only.

Comment: What do you want to do? Do you want to know how a logged in user continue to use the website after login? Or you want to save something like a shopping cart in a session?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that most implementations of microservices in the industry communicate via HTTP does not mean that microservices are meant to be used as web servers.

A microservice:

1. does not have to communicate via HTTP (though most implementations do, for convenience)
2. is not meant to receive requests issued by a web browser (although you can use a web browser to issue requests to an HTTP-listening microservice to test it)
3. is certainly not meant to generate responses containing HTML that can be rendered in a browser.

For these reasons, microservices generally do not have a concept of a session.

If you absolutely must make your microservice session-aware, and retain it stateless (so that it can still be legitimately called a microservice) then you have to have it fetch all necessary session information from your persistence store each time a request arrives, and save whatever parts of it have changed back into the persistence store right before returning its response.  But that's not how microservices are meant to work.

Generally, the way we use microservices on the web is as follows:

1. Either we have javascript running on the browser which maintains session state and issues sessionless requests to the microservice, containing authentication information if necessary, [*] or
2. We build a conventional web server which maintains session state the traditional way and is therefore ***not*** a microservice, and we have that web server internally issue sessionless requests to microservices in order to do its job.

Footnote:

[*] please note that my acknowledgement of the fact that many people do this does not in any way constitute an endorsement of this practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't manage session in a stateless server.

What you can do is that storage a unique token and its corresponding information into Redis/MemCache.

You need to storage the token instead of JSESSIONID in client.